# Apply Include() after Skip() and Take() in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Is it possible to apply `Include()` after `take()` and `skip()` method in `Linq`?

This is what I am trying to do but it seems that `Include()` method does not load selected properties.

I just want to select data to be displayed in page first and then include properties only for the selected data.

So i don't have to load properties for data that will not be displayed.

Can you tell me why this does not work, and how i can handle it?? solution can be `Linq` or `SQl`. it does not matter. thanks guys.

```
var pagedPosts = jobPosts.Skip(currentPageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);


var QueryableJobPosts = pagedPosts.AsQueryable();

var list = QueryableJobPosts.Include(m => m.User)
            .Include(m => m.ContractType)
            .Include(m => m.Place).ToList();
```

Comment: I'm almost positive `Include` *will* only return child rows for the actual rows being loaded, so your code will work already. Have you tested it and inspected the SQL it generates?

Comment: isnt it easier to create the list you want with include, then use skip/take?

Comment: @Valkyriee The right way is to build the *query* and in the end use skip/take to build the *list* ;o)

Comment: I just wanted to avoid loading properties for data that i am not using. Like I did not want to include properties for all data and then skip and take what i want

Comment: @Valkyriee so should i use include() first and then skip and take?

Comment: @Rob Yeah I checked the "list" and It just has null for User, ContractType, Place but when I use Include() right after the Dbset, of "jobPosts", it worked fine

Comment: @kisungTae Well yeah. But I mean, using `Include` *will* only include items as part of your paged set. You won't be loading entities you don't need

Comment: Oh so even if I put Include() first, this Include() will apply to only the entities obtained from Skip() and Take() method?

Comment: @Rob so I should not have put Include() last..?

Comment: @SirRufo my point exactly

Comment: @kisungTae yes you should create your `query` first then use skip/take

Comment: @kisungTae With Include you just modify the **query** - a thing that will maybe executed, when you call ToList or ToListAsync. On executing the properties only from the matched items were fetched

Comment: *Linq or SQl. it does not matter.* Well, it does matter, a lot. `Include` only works on an `IQuryable` from LINQ to Entities. Your line `pagedPosts.AsQueryable();` makes me suspect that `pagedPosts` doesn't meet that requirement.

Comment: @Gert Arnold Can you explain a bit more about what you mean by "Include only works on an IQueryable from LINQ to Entities"? You meant even if I cast "pagedPosts" to IQuryable after Skip() and Take(), Include() does not work on it?

Comment: No, the question is: what is `pagedPosts`, or `jobPosts`? Where doe these variables come from, what are their types?

Comment: This project is for kind of blog. the "jobPosts" is DbSet<JobPost>. JobPost is just an object having information about post. And PagedPosts are a list of selected JobPosts from Skip() and Take()

Comment: Then `Include` should just work, irrespective of where you put it in the statement. And doing `AsQueryable()` is redundant (and distracting).